# Use limit theorems to show that the following function is continuous on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

> Use limit theorems to show that the following function is continuous on $[0,1]$.
> $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
> e^{-\frac{1}{x}}   & :x \neq0 \\
>            0   & :  \text{$x= 0$}
> \end{cases}$$

Here is the answer which is given to me

$*$ We know that $\space\dfrac{1}{x}$ is continuous for $x \neq 0$

$*$ Hence $\space-\dfrac{1}{x}$ is continuous on $(0,1]$ and $\space e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$ continuous on $(0,1]$

$*$ For $x=0$ we must show that,
$$\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = f(0)=0$$

$*$ Since $f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$ for $x\neq 0$

$$\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0}e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$$

$*$ Consider,
$$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}e^{-\frac{1}{x}}=0$$

$\therefore$ The limit of the function as $x \rightarrow 0^+$ is equal to the function value at $x \neq 0$

That is
$$\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = f(0)=0$$

$\therefore$ $f$ is continuous at $0$

---

I feel some point are wrong here because $\lim_{x \to 0^{-}}f(x)=\infty$ so we must show for $x=0$
$$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}f(x) = f(0)=0$$ not $$\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = f(0)=0$$ this

Is there anything wrong what I am saying please tell me?

Comment: To verifying the continuity of $f$ on $[0,1]$, it is enough to check the continuity of $f$ on $(0,1]$, which you have done in the first and second *, and to see the right continuity of $f$ at $0$, which you have done in the fifth *. The rest is superfluous.

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrong when you claim that $\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=\infty$. The domain of $f$ is $[0,1]$, and therefore it doesn't make sense to mention $\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)$.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience I wanted to say $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}f(x) = f(0)=0$

Comment: It was typo now I corrected Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you haved edited it, but you are still asserting that $\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=\infty$.

Comment: But in the answer we show $\lim_{x \to 0^{}}f(x) = f(0)=0$ is this correct? since $\lim_{x \to 0^{-}}f(x) = \infty$

Comment: Yes, it is correct that $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=f(0)=0$. And, as I have explained in my answer, the expression $\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)$ makes no sense.

Comment: I think $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = f(0)=0$ means $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^{-}}f(x)=f(0)$ but here $ \lim_{x \to 0^{-}}f(x)=\infty$

Comment: So do we need to prove  $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}f(x)=f(0)=0$ ?

Comment: If I write a thousand times that, for a function whose domain is $[0,1]$ **it makes no sense** to talk about $\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)$, will you believe me?

Comment: Yes now I got it thank you

Answer (score 0):

To verifying the continuity of $f$ on $[0,1]$, it is enough to check the continuity of $f$ on $(0,1]$, which you have done in the first and second $*$, and to see the right continuity of f at $0$, which you have done in the fifth $*$. The rest is superfluous.

The evaluation of $\lim_{x \to 0^{-}}f(x)=\infty$ is correct, and $f$ is not continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and in particular at $0$. Nevertheless, it is continuous on $[0,1]$. See its graph!